# Reproducibility in a Pytorch model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

I encountered the following phenomena on a video-model I trained using PyTorch 1.8 using multiple- GPU training: A given video from the validation set is sometimes predicted as class A and sometimes in class B.

After looking around, I came across the feature `torch.use_deterministic_algorithms()`.
As I understand it, some operations on Cuda, such as `torch.nn.AvgPool3d` are not deterministically-implemented, which means that must use `torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(**mode=False**)` in order to reproduce. The simple explenation is due to multi-threading.. Makes sense.

Why such a basic operation like pooling cannot be implemented deterministically, as opposed to other operation such as `torch.nn.Conv2d` (where `mode=True` **is** valid)?

The full list of normally-nondeterministic operation:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.use_deterministic_algorithms.html